# Gas limit exceeded despite function not being complex

Tags: solidity, gas, web3j, cryptography

I am writing a function which takes in a bytes32 message and validates it against a signature (this is done without hashing to save gas). I am able to call the recover function and have it execute but I am getting a gas limit on the DeliveryVsPayment method despite it not being much more computation than recover itself. Why is this?

```
//buyer pays all the fees, seller doesn't even need to have ether to do trade
function deliveryVSpayment(bytes32 offer, uint8 v, bytes32 r,
    bytes32 s) public payable returns(bool)
{
    var (seller, quantity, price) = recover(offer, v, r, s);

    bool agreementIsValid = balances[seller] >= quantity;
    if(agreementIsValid && msg.value > uint(price) * uint(quantity))
    {
        //send over ether and tokens
        balances[msg.sender] += uint(quantity);
        balances[seller] -= uint(quantity);
        uint commission = (msg.value / 100) * transferFee;
        uint sellerAmt = msg.value - commission;
        seller.transfer(sellerAmt);
        admin.transfer(commission);
        numOfTransfers++;
        return true;
    }
    else revert();
}

// to test: suppose the offer is to sell 2 tickets at 0.102ETH
// which is 0x16A6075A7170000 WEI
// the parameters are:
// "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016a6075a7170002", 27, "0x0071d8bc2f3c9b8102bc03660d525ab872070eb036cd75f0c503bdba8a9406d8","0xb1649086e9df334e9831dc7d57cb61808f7c07d1422ef150a43f9df92c48665c"  */


function recover(bytes32 offer, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public pure
    returns (address seller, uint16 quantity, uint256 price) {
    quantity = uint16(offer & 0xffff);
    price = uint256(offer >> 16 << 16);
    seller = ecrecover(offer, v, r, s);
}
```

Remix gives the following error on each call and I noticed that my transaction fails when calling it from web3j too: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x4f6eb1449fa53c16033cebe7f8619b72e1e868f30d2af16287630f98508d8cbb

Message:

```
transact to TicketPro.buyATicketFromContract errored: Gas required exceeds limit: 3000000.  An important gas estimation might also be the sign of a problem in the contract code. Please check loops and be sure you did not sent value to a non payable function (that's also the reason of strong gas estimation).
```

**Note: I attached value to the transaction which matches the price set in the bytes32 offer variable and the key I am using has a balance that exceeds this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: the gas limit issue was hit simply because it was reverting (hence running out of gas)

I had a silly error with the number missing some zeros, once corrected this issue was solved.